# Build referenced project in current project directory instead of original directory

Tags: .net, msbuild

I am setting up an environment where developers must have read-only access to the source files of commonly used managed libraries developed in-house so that they can build everything from source, and quickly look source code up. However these source files are mounted as read-only network shares because developers using them downstream should never be able to modify the source code (only the owners of the project have write access).

My question is, when a project references one of these Library Projects, what can I put in the csproj file so that referenced projects are build in the local project's directory, instead of being built in the original directory of the project.

Right now, the behavior I am observing is that when project B has a reference to project A, Msbuild first of all builds project B in ProjectBDirectory/obj and ProjectBDirectory/bin and then copies the appropriates files from ProjectBDirectory/bin to ProjectADirectory/bin. What I need msbuild to do is build project B in ProjectADirectory/obj + ProjectADirectory/bin instead, since developers cannot have write access to the original's project's B directory.

I need this configuration to be as transparent as possible (no change to the csproj file of ProjectB so that the team working on ProjectB is not impacted). Any help or idea would be greatly appreciated.

We want to avoid using NuGet packages here, because the libraries change often and are always backward-compatible, so for this particular circumstance the overhead of managing packages and versions is not worth it. We used them but while they have value elsewhere, we found they are too much hassle for us here.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the point. You'r in an organisation that have "shared" project that contains all common stuff. This common stuff can't be modified by everyone because someone could break something on a project, i'm right ?

You should not have source file in a network shares. Always work on local checked out sources files. That will leads to performance problems.

"We want to avoid NuGet packages", i don't understand why ? even if you want to be backward-compatible a old projects will have his own version of the package and always will work the same way. I understand that is a additionnal managing cost but i think this is actually a good practice.

I see some projects using git submodules because of shared "business" code changing every days. i think it can be a trail.

This is a hard question, i hope i helped you.

Comment: Yes your remarks were helpful, thanks very much for your help, I'll wait to see if someone comes with a technical way to achieve what I asked with msbuild,